# Adobe Dynamic Tag Manager (DTM) - Rolling back to previous versions

Tags: dynamic, tags, versioning, google-tag-manager, adobe-analytics

We need to have the ablity to roll back to a previous version of a published tag, much like the way Google Tag Manager has versioning.

For instance, if we go through the publication authentication, then find that a bug exists and need to drop back to the most recent known working version.

Adobe does not provide any documentation on the subject. Implying the feature does not exist.

What is the correct process to provide roll back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTM versioning isn't completely non-existent but I will agree that (IMO) it falls embarrassingly short of the mark compared to other tag managers.

If you have the permissions to see it, you should see a **History** tab where the other main tabs for your Property are located (e.g. **Overview**,**Rules**). This tab will list a history of when and what things were published.  From there, you can click the **Edit** link for an entry and go to the editing page for the entry (e.g. the tool config or a rule).

Up at the top right of the editing page for whatever tool config/rule, etc. is a blue box that shows the current Revision # and date, e.g. `Revision 1  Feb 16, 2015`. If you click on it, you can select a previous revision from the dropdown (*Oddly, it does not autoselect/show the revision you selected when selected from the **History** page*).

When you select a revision from the dropdown, it will show a side-by-side of the revision you selected vs. the current revision, and at the bottom of the page, you can choose which revision to select.

Select the one you want to revert to, and it will now show the editing page but with the selected revision.  Save it and Approve/Publish.

**Note:** DTM currently has no way to roll everything back to a previous revision all at once, so you will need to individually go through each tool, rule, etc. to make sure they are rolled back to the desired revision.

**Note:** You do not have to go through the **History** tab to see the revision dropdown for a given tool/rule editing page; you can just navigate to any tool or rule and see it.  However, the **History** tab will help determine which items actually need to be reverted.

Comment: Thank you. Disappointing that there isn't a all tags at once rollback, which is something we need.